How to request for a software package to be updated in OpenSUSE?
I am a maintainer of SafeEyes, which is a program to reduce eye strain by reminding the user to periodically blink their eyes/do eye excercises.
OpenSUSE repositories host an older version of this software, which is incompatible with Python 3.12. The problem has been fixed upstream.
How to request the OpenSUSE packagers to package a new version?
Unlike Arch, OpenSUSE does not seem to have a button to mark packages out of date.

OpenSuse has reliable infrastructure that tell the maintainers when there's available software updates, that's why you usually don't see such buttons on mainline distro packaging infrastructure. Assuming your package is this one, that is already being monitored. It still might be simply a matter of maintainer time that stops an update being rolled out by default.
You can, in general, make a request for updating on the tumbleweed package request tracker by forking the package repo, doing the update in the package recipe, and opening a merge request; but what you're saying in the question is "more pressing" in a way: You say the currently packaged version doesn't work with the version of Python they're shipping, and needs to be updated to work correctly.
So, that's a bug, and you should file a bug report on the OpenSuSE bug tracker.
I'd start by opening the bug against their Tumbleweed rolling release, as that gets updated the quickest. In there, you can kindly ask whether you need to file bugs for other releases as well – I'm not that familiar with the OpenSuSE packaging process, but the people potentially updating the package will probably know best.
Thanks for helping getting software packaged!

I filed a bug, and they fixed it in a day!

@ArchismanPanigrahi :) that's good! And I meant to say that software authors like you are extremely appreciated amongst other FOSS software authors, because you care enough about the users of your software that you don't only write it, "throw it over the fence" and let people use it as-is, you actually care that people are able to use it. Thank you!
